# How to reference database in php class

Tags: php, mysql, class

```
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_NAME = "rawr";
$DB_USER = "rawr";
$DB_PASS = "hunter2!";
$tableprefix = "hunter_";
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
    class ACL
{....
```

I currently have that, but I am unable to use that db connection in all of my ACL commands. How can I gain the ability to use that db connection inside my class?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, It's honestly not real.

Comment: I got that, I read bash.org as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $mysqli is just out of scope. You have to options:

1) Use global variables.

```
function XXXX () {
    global $mysqli;
    ...
}
```

2) Pass it into the constructor (this is better)

```
public function __construct($mysqli) {
    $this->_mysqli = $mysqli;
}
```

And then refer to it from within your class just with `$this->_mysqli`

Comment: unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Comment: what PHP version are you using?

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I placed $ sign in the wrong place. Try with `$this->_mysqli = $mysqli;`

Comment: Wait, I must pass it into my constructor? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Well, if you want to use the DB connection in your class, you have 3 options: you create the connection within the class, you create it outside and reference by globals, you create it outside and pass it inside of the constructor to store it, which is the best approach. `$my_acl = new ACL($mysqli);`

Comment: But that ends up being messy don't you think?

Comment: Not at all. If your class works with certain resources, they should explicitly be passed into the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that mysqli instance to your ACL class when you instantiate it.  It does not automatically know about local variables declared outside of the class declaration.

Comment: Would I do this in construct? How would I do it?

Comment: Yes.  Just accept a parameter of `$db` or something in your `__construct()` function, and pass that in when you create a new `ACL`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the connection you are using is in the right environment.
You can do it e.g. with `global`:

```
class ACL {
    function DoSomething() {
        global $mysqli;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ACL {

       public function __construct() {
            $DB_HOST = "localhost";
            $DB_NAME = "rawr";
            $DB_USER = "rawr";
            $DB_PASS = "hunter2!";
            $tableprefix = "hunter_";
            $conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                   exit();
            } else {       
                   $this->conn = $conn;
            }
       }

       public function command1()
       {
            //use connection object as $this->conn 
            ///your code
       }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in more than one connection per php page load?

Comment: yes...you can write another private function to close the connection and then call it in all your commands or change the private function connect() to public function __construct()

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your mysqli in a class such as:

```
class database {
    // do database stuff here
}
```

and extend ACL

```
class ACL extends database {
    // do acl stuff here with all your database stuff available
}
```

Comment: Although this works, it is against OOP. ACL is not a Database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.  Abstract your database connection into a separate utility class:

```
<?php
class DB
{
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_NAME = "rawr";
    const DB_USER = "rawr";
    const DB_PASS = "hunter2!";

    protected static $instance;
    public static function instance()
    {
        if (empty(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new mysqli(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS, self::DB_NAME);
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

This isn't inversion of control, but database access is so central to most apps that it's pretty safe to use as a pattern.

```
<?php

// Note: make sure DB class is loaded!

class ACL // Note: this doesn't extend DB!
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // you can now access your $mysqli object with DB::instance()
    }
}
```